# How to generate svg inside thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, svg, thymeleaf

I would like to generate a html page using spring thymeleaf template. The page should contain a `<svg>` section. The content of the section is dynamically generated from java code. I tried to use `[[${var}]]` syntax but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Thymeleaf is pretty flexible, you can use `th:utext` for inserting the svg content like so:

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" th:utext="${var}">
</svg>
```

Comment: Your answer is in danger of deletion.  You might want to expand and explain a bit.

Comment: @David Hoelzer - this fragment worked for me. The code contains all new information - use th:utext instead of [[]]. What else do you need?

Comment: Explain why this works and how it answers the question. :)